# Django queries: When to use ' '

Tags: mysql, django

I just don't get why sometimes have to use something like Model.objects.filter('fieldname'=foo) and sometimes it is okay to use just fieldname without the ''.

Could you explain that to me, please?

Comment: `'fieldname'=foo` is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: As for me i'm prefer a single quote when string acts as key of dictionary (`cred['password']` or `getattr(person, 'location')`) and double quote in all other cases (`site_name="stackoverflow.com"`, `doc.xpath("//div[@class='article']")`).

Not to forget, if a single or double quotation mark is part of the string itself, the string must be enclosed in double or single quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string as a field nane in filter() method of django ORM ,  you can pass field value as a string.

Model.objects.fiiter('fieldname'=foo) its wrong syntex,

It can be:

Model.objects.fiiter(fieldname='foo')
  Or
foo = 'abc'
Model.objects.fiiter(fieldname=foo)

Comment: Dear Ashutosh and everyone else
Thank you. I made a mistake in my post, but I meant something like this:
Model.objects.filter(fieldname__isnull=True).order_by('-model_id').values_list('model_id', 'model_date').distinct()
There I have the isnull check on fieldname without '' and the ordering with ''.